# Selecting a Photo from the Gallery and getting its TimeStamp

Tags: android, timestamp, photo

In my android application I select photo from phone's gallery or phone's storage file memory and view it on Image-view. Moreover, I also want the selected photo's Timestamp.

I got succeed to fetch photo from gallery and show it on to image-view. However, I didn't get the selected photo's Timestamp.

Any suggestion, how to get selected photo's timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String picturePath = getPath(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri );
    File file = new File(picturePath);
    Date fileDate = new Date(file.lastModifiedDate());
    int timestamp = Math.round(fileDate.getTime()/1000);
   }
}

public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
        result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
        return result;
    }
```